# Android Cursor odd and even rows into MatrixCursor

Tags: android, listview, cursor, listview-adapter, matrixcursor

Hee guys,

I got 2 `ListViews`, one for the left side and one for the right side. However I have one `Cursor` with values. Now I want to get the even rows from the cursor and put that in a `matrixcursor` to fill the left `ListView` and with the odds I want to fill the right side.

However i got like 9 columns, is there anyway to just put the whole row into a `matrixCursor` without selecting each column by itself? So that when something changes about the db or anything I dont have to manually adjust the columns.

Maybe I could just use a Cursor instead of a `MatrixCursor`, which would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
MatrixCursor lCursor;
MatrixCursor rCursor;
String[] columnNames = new String[mCursor.getColumnCount()];
mCursor.moveToFirst();
for (int j = 0; j < mCursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
    columnNames[j] = mCursor.getColumnName(j);
}
lCursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
rCursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);

if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        if ((i & 1) == 0) {
            String[] values = new String[mCursor.getColumnCount()];
            for (int j = 0; j < mCursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                values[j] = mCursor.getString(j);
            }
            lCursor.addRow(values);
        } else {
            String[] values = new String[mCursor.getColumnCount()];
            for (int j = 0; j < mCursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                values[j] = mCursor.getString(j);
            }
            rCursor.addRow(values);
        }
    }
    left.setAdapter(new HomeMenuAdapter(MainActivity.getContext(),
            lCursor));
    right.setAdapter(new HomeMenuAdapter(MainActivity.getContext(),
            rCursor));
}
```